# To read NFC tag ,should the mobile have the same application which used to write that tag?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

If I use any application for writing in tags for example task luncher let's say to write URL

then is it possible that any mobile has NFC can read it ?

Or should the mobile have the same application which write the tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Tags can be read with any app / with android stock apps.
If a ApplicationRecord is attached to the Tag, the target App is launched.

But in short: No, you do not need a tag WRITER to read tags.

Comment: Adding on it, if the NDEF record is of the Well-Known Format, then the phone should be able to handle it without any need for a specific app. If you are creating a custom record, then you need an app which can understand and interpret that record.